# Hyperledger Fabric: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

we get this error when trying to instantiate a chaincode:

```
2019-03-14 23:17:01.917 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 152d start-could not recreate container <dev-peer1-kp-mycc-1.0>, because of Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer1-kp-mycc-1.0: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

we can see a file `/var/run/docker.sock` on the host:

```
$ ls /var/run/docker.sock
/var/run/docker.sock
```

how can we fix this?

EDIT: we are using pretty much the same config as [[1](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/makeDocker.sh#L256)] except that we are not mounting `/var/run` to the container. That seems a big security loop hole according to [[2](https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html)]

Comment: Is it mounted inside the container ?

Comment: No, its not mounted inside the container. see https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html for why

Comment: Yes i know its a dangerous thing to do, just wondering how this issue related to fabric

Comment: Maybe you need to configure the docker daemon with something like this? `-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: another thing, why it says `/host/var/run/docker.sock` and not `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: seems like an issue, check this https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/125

Comment: that's because of this line: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/makeDocker.sh#L298

Comment: So it mounts the whole `/var/run` from the host to make docker.sock available inside the container but you disabled it?

Comment: Yes, but we don't want to do that as it seems a security risk. the issue is related to fabric in the sense it ought to provide a way for developers to run it without exposing such security loopholes.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't need to depend on mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` in your container. Another option you might go with enabling docker daemon through [tcp connection](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) and then modify the value of `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT` to become `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375`

> Consider check which IP you would like to expose the API to it.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: We had to mount `/var/run` to the docker container to make it work.

Re: exposing docker daemon over tcp, it doesn't really make any difference w.r.t. the security vulnerability since in both cases (file mount vs tcp) the daemon has been exposed to the container which is what the vulnerability is about.

If we try to set CORE_VM_ENDPOINT to http://172.17.0.1:2375 there is some error to the effect of connection refused since there is no one listening on the port.

To fix that, it appears one has to enable docker daemon (`dockerd -H ...`). We tried to do that but got some error saying PID exists. It looks like one has to restart the daemon and we didn't want to do that. So we settled for the file mount option.

We were thinking we will shut down the peer after instantiating the chaincode and thus take care of the security vulnerability but if we do that then invoking the chaincode fails since invoke again relies on communicating with the daemon process.

```
2019-03-18 23:23:39.108 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> DEBU 04d ESCC invoke result: response:<status:500 message:"failed to execute transaction 9c8928ffda960c89225682d0c4d0936342b60c687dd7ea0547378a88fd5f6749: [channel dscsa] could not launch chaincode mycc:1.0: error starting container: error starting container: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer1-kp-mycc-1.0: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory" >
```

Comment: I think I am running into the same issue. Could you please explain what you did? You said you had to mount `/var/run` to docker container. But how did you that exactly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem using Docker Desktop 3.0+ on MacOS, with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3 instantiating an smart contract. We change the Docker version to 2.5+ and everything worked fine.